# How do I plot a non-linear model using matplotlib?

Tags: matplotlib, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I'm a bit lost as to how to proceed to achieve this. Normally with a linear model, when I perform linear regressions, I simply take my training data (x) and and my output data (y) and plot them using matplotlib. Now I have 3 features with and my output/observation (y). Can anyone guide me as to how to graph this kind of model using matplotlib? My goal is to fit a polynomial model and graph a polynomial using matplotlib.

```
%matplotlib inline
import sframe as frame
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from sklearn import datasets, linear_model

# Initalize SFrame
sales = frame.SFrame('kc_house_data.gl/')

# Separate data into test and training data 
train_data,test_data = sales.random_split(.8,seed=0)

# Organize data into training and testing data 

train_x = train_data[['sqft_living', 'bedrooms', 'bathrooms']].to_dataframe().values
train_y = train_data[['price']].to_dataframe().values
test_x = test_data[['sqft_living', 'bedrooms', 'bathrooms']].to_dataframe().values
test_y = test_data[['price']].to_dataframe().values


# Create a model using sklearn with multiple features
regr = linear_model.LinearRegression(fit_intercept=True, n_jobs=2)

# test predictions
regr.predict(train_x)

# Prepare to plot the data
```

Note:

The train_x variable contains my 3 features, and my train_y contains the output data. I use SFrame to contain the data. SFrame has the ability to convert itself into a dataframe (used in Pandas). Using the conversion I am able to grab the values.

Comment: Does this essentially mean that your function has 3 independent variables instead of one? If so, that's indeed hard to visualize.

Comment: I see what you mean now. I think I was aiming towards turning my features into a polynomial of degree 3 and then plotting that. I found some documentation on sklearn about Polynomial features. I'm still investigating how to use it. http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/58739/polynomial-regression-using-scikit-learn

Comment: @Andras The problem with the documentation is that, although it looks like the examples are plotted using matplotlib, an example is never shown of how the author of the documentation did that. http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/linear_model.html#polynomial-regression-extending-linear-models-with-basis-functions

Comment: My question was actually a pretty naive one; I have no experience with machine learning and nonlinear programming.

Comment: @AndrasDeak I guess I was pretty confused. When you mentioned 3 independent variables I immediately began search around and found a [Matlab graph plotting thread about that](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/114036-plotting-3-variables-of-a-single-function?requestedDomain=www.mathworks.com) and I immediately began to think I was plotting a something like what I had found. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: To make it up to you, [here's how that figure was made](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/linear_model/plot_polynomial_interpolation.html#example-linear-model-plot-polynomial-interpolation-py), found it via [this](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.PolynomialFeatures.html#sklearn.preprocessing.PolynomialFeatures) :)

Comment: @AndrasDeak Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than plotting a non-linear model with multiple discrete features at once, I have found that simply observing each and every feature against my observation/output was better and easier for my research.